# Set variables with mysqlimport

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

I'm rewriting a 'LOAD DATA INFILE'-query to the [mysqlimport program](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html).

From:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/filename.csv' INTO TABLE my_table
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
     (zipcode, @date_variable, `code`, @time_from, @time_to) 
     SET `date` = STR_TO_DATE(@datevar, '%d-%m-%Y'),
         `timefrom` = CONCAT(@timefromvar, '00'),
         `timeto` = CONCAT(@timetovar, '00');
```

To:

```
mysqlimport --host='****' --user='****' --password='****' --port='3306' --local --fields-terminated-by=';' --lines-terminated-by='\n' --columns='pc, @datevar, `code`, @timefromvar, @timetovar' db_name /tmp/my_table.csv
```

But I can't seem to find how to SET the variables `date`, `timefrom`, `timeto`. Does anyone know if this is possible? Or do I just need to execute a UPDATE query after the import?

**Update:** 
[Probably no support yet, look here for a work-arround](http://blog.dgaspar.com/2010/08/01/the-set-clause/)